# Missing "Merge Pages" Button on Facebook Fanpage

Tags: facebook, merge, migration, facebook-page

I am owner of two Facebook FanPages and I want to *merge these two pages*.

**[A] facebook.com/norbert.niederkofler.5**

- It's a normal FanPage, which I have created last year
- This FanPage has a lot of posts and pictures

**[B] facebook.com/niederkofler.norbert**

- This FanPage was converted from a User Profile **Profile to Business Page Migration**
- This Page now has about 5000 Likes but no posts.

---

I went to the page I want to keep **[A]**

- https://www.facebook.com/norbert.niederkofler.5
- Edit Page -> Edit Settings:

There is no line, where I can merge FanPages.

---

When I do the same thing from the other FanPage **[B]** I can see the option.

---

Can someone help me to resolve the problem?

Thank You!

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You can see the merge option only in the page that has more likes. You can merge the little one to the bigger one. Not the opposite.